# c# console type in capslock

Tags: c#, console, uppercase

I wanted to create a little "Terminal"-Game, where everything is in uppercase.
But when you type with console readline, the input isn't all uppercase, and i haven't found a solution yet.

So if i type "login" i want the console to type "LOGIN" in realtime.

At the moment, my code looks like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        slowType("TERMINALTEST V1.0 CORP", 50, 100);
        Console.WriteLine();
        slowType(">", 50, 100);
        string temp = Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void slowType(string input, int minvelo, int maxvelo)
    {
        Random temp = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.Write(input[i]);
            Thread.Sleep(temp.Next(minvelo, maxvelo));
        }
    }
```

and i want to replace

```
string temp = Console.ReadLine();
```

with

```
string temp = MethodForTypingUppercase();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will take each character 1 at a time, exit if enter is pressed, else we uppercase it, suppress the original character, and then write the uppercased version.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string test = GetCapitalizedInput();
    Console.WriteLine("Captured: " + test);
    Console.ReadLine();
}

static string GetCapitalizedInput()
{
    string input = "";
    while (true)
    {
        var keypress = Console.ReadKey(true); // suppress original output
        if (keypress.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter)
        {
            break;
        }
        string uppercased = keypress.KeyChar.ToString().ToUpper();
        input += uppercased;
        Console.Write(uppercased);
    }
    return input;
}
```

Comment: Instead of backspacing the keypress, you should use `Console.ReadKey(true)`, this makes it so that the entered character doesn't appear.

Comment: `var keypress = Console.ReadKey(true);`

Comment: Edited: That does look a little better